# Are there any single-screen human-vs-human go clients/programs available?

Tags: go

This is a question about Go software, so it might not be the correct place to ask this, but I expect it to be the best place. ;)

I want to give a group of people a quick overview on Go but I don't have the resources to obtain actual material, so I was looking for a basic sandbox program and that turned out more difficult than I expected.

So, a single-screen / hot-seat go client. Where one (or two players) could run a human-human go game on a single machine (Mac/Windows/both but preferably Mac)

Comment: Some suggestions here: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1221448/virtual-online-go-board

Comment: Oh, so it seems cgoban does allow this after all. Thanks you for pointing out this thread to me!

Comment: CGoban does it. I already tested this a while ago.

Comment: If you're on iOS there are a number of good Go apps that will do what you're asking. It might be more fun on an iPad than a desktop, since it will be closer to tabletop.

Answer (score 2):

Almost any SGF editor. Most common choice would be - cgoban (KGS client). Just create an empty board, and begin playing.

Alternatives: MultiGo (windows only?), eidogo (online, but the board is small), SmartGo.